# Bash copy file and replace string in file name

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file with SNAPSHOT in the name and I want to copy the file over to a new destination. I am not working within that directory, so I'll be using direct paths. I'm not great with bash commands so this is giving me some trouble. I feel though this should be very trivial.

This will be put into a script that will be copy hundreds of JAR files with the SNAPSHOT string attached to the file name. Here is something I have been working with but has been giving me trouble if my current working directory is not in the tree level of those jars.

```
cp "${SRC_PATH}"/grid-start/target/grid-start-* "${INSTALLER_PATH}"/boot/$(ls "${SRC_PATH}"/grid-start/target/*SNAP* | sed "s/-SNAPSHOT//")
```

Scenario:

File: `/home/build/src/trunk/grid-start/target/grid-start-1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Dest: `/home/build/installer/boot/grid-start-1.6.jar`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this bash script for you. It should serve its purpose.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# copier.sh

for f in $(find /home/build/ -name '*SNAPSHOT*');
do
    filename=${f##*/};
    filename=${filename/-SNAPSHOT};
    cp $f ./installer/$filename;
done

# EOF
```

Usage: run `copier.sh` from /home/build/ and it will copy(and remove -SNAPSHOT) to the `/home/build/installer/` directory

It is kind of ugly, but it does what it should do.